# Question on NP and its closure properties

Tags: polynomials, regular-language

Is this true or false?  If $L_1$∈ **NP** and $L_2$∈ **NP**, then $L_1$∩ $L_2$ ∈ **NP**.

**NP** = nondeterministic polynomial

Comment: The N stands for "nondeterministic," not "non."

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Sorry, typo.  Thanks, I've fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true, you can use the pair of witnesses as a witness for the intersection and then verify both of them.

Comment: So something like, if you have evidence that $x$ ∈ $L_1$ is true and $y$ ∈ $L_2$ is true, then the intersection is true?

Comment: Yeah basically.  But it is in NP because the combined evidence $(x,y)$ isn't very large compared to the problem size because $x$ and $y$ themselves aren't, and we have a way to verify it quickly.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the proof, please? Then I can mark the question as answered :)